# JavaFX keep scroll event activated when disabling text edition

Tags: java, javafx, text

I have a javaFX Node which is javaFX TextArea.

I would like to disable the edition BUT to be able to scroll on the text also.

I know that "setMouseTransparent(boolean)" deactivate all the mouse events detection.

Here is my code so far :

```
private void manageReadability(Node control, boolean writeMode) {

if (writeMode) {
  control.setMouseTransparent(false);
} else {
  control.setMouseTransparent(true);
  // I would like to be able to scroll the text field
}
```

Is there a way to disable the text editing but to keep the mouse listening on the scroll event only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a text area in JavaFX you just need to set the editable flag.

```
myTextArea.setEditable(false);
```

This will allow you to copy text, scroll, etc - but will not allow you to edit.

Comment: Was really easy, I did not see this simple method... Thank you very much !